Intuition behind Principal Component Analysis: linear combinations of original dimensions vs the PC direction as linear function of y and x
So in this example here the Principal Components (PC) are:
$$  
\begin{align}
PC_1 (Size) &= 0.707 * Height + 0.707 * Diameter  \quad (1)\\ 
PC_2 (Shape) &= 0.707 * Height - 0.707 * Diameter  \quad (2) 
\end{align}
$$
But in the graph the PC1 (Size) direction is given by the equation $Diameter = Height$, ie smth like $y=x$ where $y$ = Diameter and $x$ = Height.
How does this correspond with the definition of PC1 where the equation is $PC1 = 0.707 y+ 0.707x$ ?

source: https://www.kaggle.com/code/ryanholbrook/principal-component-analysis

You're misreading the figure.
If you look closely you can see that the point with coordinate $(0,0)$ is in the middle of the figure (at the intersection of the two lines). Hence the PC1 direction line passes through $(0,0)$ and its equation is $diameter = height$
To see the link between the lines and the equations you do the following
In equation $(2)$ you write the second principal component as a linear combination of height and diameter. These coefficients correspond to a point in your height-diameter plot with coordinates $(0.707, -0.707)$.
The line passing through that point and the origin is the line you're interested in.

Ah I see, my bad thanks for the tip! I corrected the questions.
But then PC1 equation is diameter = height. How does that relate to the linear combination of PC1 = diameter + height? Like how do I rearrange the equations?

@yyyLLL see my edit.
